# What are the best settings for a video export to Adobe Premiere (CS6)?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Whenever I import a video rendered in Blender into Premiere, the video in Premiere only shows a random frame from a different source for the duration of the video.

My current workflow (with workaround) is:

1. Put frames in Blender 2.75 video sequence editor
2. Render out animation with H.264 format/file format
3. Run through Handbrake (because when I put the file straight into Premiere the problem above happens)
4. Use the new Handbrake video file in Premiere

I need a way to cut out the Handbrake steps, does anyone have working render settings that I could use to export to Adobe Premiere?

Comment: Don't use a video format to export from blender. Use an image sequence in EXR, PNG or Tiff format (@16bit if you care for the quality) Import those images into premiere as a sequence.

Comment: I don't believe this is an option for me because when I tried to do this I only got a one frame sequence. I'm pretty sure it happened because the frames I have are irregularly (non-sequentially) named and this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9kH7R54tkU) says they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was following cegaton's suggestion (I don't know if I'm able to say a comment answered my question) in which they told me to import the frames as a sequence.

At first I thought I was unable to because of the frame's irregular naming pattern, but then I found this thread (https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/926297) which suggested to do a batch rename in Adobe Bridge to give all the frames a consistent naming scheme.

To batch rename, open up bridge, select the files you want to rename (hopefully they are already in order) and go to tools -> batch rename.

Answer (score 0):

i open the rendered h264 animation files from blender in windows movie maker save them from there, and then they'l work in premier pro. if i don't put them through movie maker first they just bounce right off prem pro, it says they are damaged, but after banging them through windows movie maker they're fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that every time you re-encode you are likely to loose information and degrade the quality of the video.